# jquery click takes two times to fire angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to highlight the selected li from list. I am using jquery in angular 2. Sometimes it takes 2 time to fire the event and change color

This is the jquery I am using

```
function highlight(){

var selector = 'li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
}
```

Part of my html

```
<li id="auth-auth" (click)="linkedPressed($event)"><img src="app/resources/i_arrow_{{ showAuthPic }}.png" id="auth-auth" ><img src="app/resources/i_acordian_folder_closed_page.png"  class="myimage" id="auth-auth" />Authorization & Authentication</li>
                <ol *ngIf="showAuth">
                    <li id="radius" class = "li-padding" (click)="linkedPressed($event)"><img src="app/resources/i_acordian_page.png" class="myimage" id="radius"/>RADIUS</li>
                    <li id="authentication" class = "li-padding" (click)="linkedPressed($event)"><img src="app/resources/i_acordian_page.png" class="myimage" id="authentication" />Authentication</li>
                </ol>
```

In the function linkedPressed I am calling highlight

I solved it with

```
function highlight(which){

    var selector = "#" + which;
     $("li").removeClass('active');
      $(selector).addClass('active');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As function `highlight()` is invoked from `linkedPressed()`. The jQuery event handler is attached only when `li` is clicked thus it works when clicked second time. Also **note** on every click another event handler is getting attached.

Directly bind the event handler on page/view load.